# Different versions of react-scripts in package.json and "npm view react-scripts version" - how can it be?

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

package.json in my project has react-scripts@3.0.1

I installed packages by "npm i", and when i put command "npm view react-scripts version" - I get version 5.0.1

Why? What have I done wrong?

```
PS C:\Users\admin\source\repos\eventsystem\EventSystem\ClientApp> npm view react-scripts version
5.0.1
PS C:\Users\admin\source\repos\eventsystem\EventSystem\ClientApp> npm list -g
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- grunt-cli@1.4.3
`-- verdaccio@5.8.0
```

Comment: Check if you have `^` or '~' in package.json before version number

Comment: I deleted ^ before version number in package.json (now 3.0.1), then removed folder node_modules and the ran "npm i" -  but npm view react-scripts version returns
5.0.1

Comment: Do you have pnpm-lock file? Also after changes in packeage.json try to install packages again.

Comment: removed package-lock, removed node_modules, ran npm i, after that npm view react-scripts return 5.0.1 instead of 3.0.1